# Method threw 'org.apache.axiom.om.OMException' exception. Cannot evaluate org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMSourcedElementImpl.toString()

Tags: java, exception, axiom

I generated a clinet using Axis 2 JAXBRI.
I got different objects, ObjectFactory, Stub and CallbackHandler.

I started making a request but I get an error adding the header, namely the following lines:
 `factory.createOMElement(new org.apache.axiom.om.ds.jaxb.JAXBOMDataSource(wsContext, param));`

Added also this dependency ([Java client Axis2 OMException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42355009/java-client-axis2-omexception)) but not working.

[Exception (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQI5Z.png)

Also, I have to sign this request with certificates, if someone has an article, I will be glad.

If someone can help, I can add on skype and talk.

Comment: Do you have a test project that can be used to reproduce the problem?

Comment: The problem has been resolved.
The problem was in the object that was sent as param.
I was sending a string but in fact I have to create an object and send it.